# Why does scalaz.NonEmptyList not support common list operations like "find"

Tags: list, scala, scalaz

I have a `NonEmptyList` instance and I want to find (in order) the first element that matches a predicate. With scalas `List` I can do `myList.find(predicate)`, however scalaz `NonEmptyList` does not support such an operation, so this is not working here.

Why is that?

Is there a better way than doing `myNonEmptyList.toList.find(predicate)`?

Comment: you can do `myNonEmptyList.list.find(predicate)` 2 chars shorter :D or convert implicitly

Answer (score 5):

- https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.2.0/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Foldable.scala#L129
- https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.2.0/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/FoldableSyntax.scala#L23

You can use `findLeft` or `findRight`.